# How to connect to virtual /dev/ttyX from same machines pts terminal?

Tags: command-line, configuration, tty

I want to get output/input from `/dev/ttyX` console (normally accessible directly using keys `ctrl+alt+FNr`,
where Nr is number of `/dev/ttyNr`: `ctrl+alt+f4` access `/dev/tty4`). 
I want to view and control these consoles over ssh (which normally uses virtual `/dev/pts` console like desktop applications (xterm) does). I need something to either connect from normal virtual terminal (`/dev/pts/Y`) to `/dev/ttyX`, or switch consoles.

For physical devices like `/dev/ttySX`, `/dev/ttyUSBX` utilities like `minicom` and `screen` after setting baud rate are working well. I tried to apply similar methods for virtual `/dev/ttyX` but sessions only hang: output send from `screen` gets to tty, but are not executed and input does show (`ctrl+alt+f4` shows output but it does not get executed, neither while writing anything shows up in `screen`:  like I would be using `echo nonsense >> /dev/tty4` but not having real session). `minicom` does the same. Either I am abusing utilities or I don't know how to properly setup tty's.

Should I do something with `getty`? It seems that it is important here too.

Any ideas how to connect to `/dev/tty` from `pts` console?
I am using Linux with systemd if that is important.

Answer (score 2):

Why? :)  The `/dev/ttyX` terminals are just software terminals provided by the kernel.  The `/dev/pts/*` terminals are essentially pipes connected to `/dev/ptmx`, and according to `man pts` on my closest-available RHEL6 system, the interface is identical between the two.  If you're implementing a program to replace a terminal interface, using `/dev/ptmx` is the generally "right" way to do it anyway.  On a Linux system, the filename is all that really differs.  You could probably just create a symlink named like `/dev/ttyX` after creating the `pty` if the filename is really that important.

If your goal is to remotely control the screen attained when you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, for example, just change `/etc/iniitab` to open your alternate "remote control" program on `/dev/tty4`.  Normally it starts up a mingetty, but there's no reason you couldn't run whatever you want there.  You may also look at the mingetty man page to see what else you can do with mingetty; it's capable of several interesting things.